# How can one use a polymer component inside a react component ? Is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, polymer

I have used google's polymer to make web components but i am also very interested in giving react a try. So i want to know whether it is possible to use the polymer component from inside the render function of a react component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible !
I did it using a method thats kinda bit complicated but i would love to share it.

if you have already used polymer then just directly use the polymer the way you use it any other polymer element.
all you have to do is convert this react folder to a js. 
You can follow this tutorial in order to convert a jsx to js. and use any polymer element without a problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WUATF3hGUQ

This is not my tutorial but something i saw on youtube . 
all credits for this tutorial go to codingwithjesse

As asked by WiredPraire , i would like to show you with an example

this is my index.html : 
[image]

This is poly-react.html the polymer element:
[image]

This is my polyreact.jsx which also has polymer element inside

[image]

and the polymer inside above jsx started working with this transformation which can be done using the tutorial:

[image]

The index file also has to be changed like this:

[image]

hope this helps!!!!!!!!

Comment: As links go stale, can you please provide specific instructions here? And, I don't see how the topic of that video helps address the question you posted.

Comment: well i was just giving a link on how to convert a jsx to js , for me the polymer component wasn't working if i did not transform the jsx to js manually. and when i transformed it to js manually then it started working , just thought i should let people know it was that easy .

Comment: @WiredPrairie bro i m kinda new and it says to post images you need to have 10 reputation points ? can you help me with that .

Comment: @WiredPrairie You can download the images and check the code !! let me know if you have a problem !! i will be glad to help!!