# React JSX inside a polymer? it's possible?

Tags: reactjs, polymer, jsx, web-component

Is it possible to use JSX inside a polymer component?

I found a lot of approaches, but I think it's not possible to do JSX in a polymer app that is already running.

[How to use react inside a polymer component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175599/how-to-use-react-inside-a-polymer-component)

[How can one use a polymer component inside a react component ? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594809/how-can-one-use-a-polymer-component-inside-a-react-component-is-it-possible)